# How to eliminate duplicate or repeated values on textbox.text

Tags: asp.net

i used ajax control ModalPopupExtender.ModalPopupextender has panel. in that panel, text boxes and gridview placed and OK button. it has three textboxes and gridview and ok button sequentially. While edit button of gridview and after entering the some intextboxes, the text of textboxes repetedly show on textbox with camma. i dont know it is happening please help me

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug with the specific version of the Ajax Control Toolkit you're using.  We ran into this and at the time moved back to an older version of the toolkit.  We were using 3.0.30930, which was broken, so we moved back to 3.0.30512, which worked.  In our case it was specific to a modal popup extender and an update panel.

Edit:  Looks like this was fixed in [build 40412](http://ajaxcontroltoolkit.codeplex.com/workitem/25011)